# Scan folder for .shp extension and add to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I am trying to scan a folder for all .shp files and add them to my leaflet map as a layer. The problem I'm having is that AJAX doesn't appear to be able to scan a folder, rather it is only capable of searching for specific files. I need it to be able to scan the folder because the .shp files will be overwritten periodically with new file names and I don't know how many files will be there at a given time. If there are no files in the folder, I need a popup to notify that maps are unavailable (this works in the current website). The code for this section is provided below. I've tried using PHP, but I can't figure out how to incorporate that with JavaScript.

I'm not a programmer, but I have stumbled through developing our website on my own. You can view it here: http://hsvfms.azurewebsites.net/map.html

If I haven't provided enough information or have given this information out of context, please let me know. Also, check out the website and let me know what you think.

```
var noMaps = L.control ();
var profile01 = new L.LayerGroup();
var profile02 = new L.LayerGroup();

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"Aldridge_Unet/",
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(.shp)").each(function(){
            var mapList=[];
            var profile0 = new L.Shapefile(mapList[0],{color:'DarkCyan',fillOpacity:'0.5', opacity:'5', weight:'1'}).addTo(profile01);
            var profile1 = new L.Shapefile(mapList[1],{color:'DarkCyan',fillOpacity:'0.5', opacity:'5', weight:'1'}).addTo(profile02);
        })
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        if(xhr.status==404){
            noMaps = L.control ({position:'bottomleft'});
            noMaps.onAdd = function(map) { var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
                div.innerHTML += '<img src="Images/map_not_available.png" alt="legend" style="width:275px;height:75px;background-color:white">';
            return div;};
        }
    }
});

var overlays = [{groupName:"Inundation Boundaries", expanded:false, layers:{"Max Value":profile01}},];
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done. JavaScript code cannot access the filesystem of the computer the browser is running in (let alone watch a path for changes).

AJAX (and `fetch` and similar techniques) are just ways of fetching information from another computer (the web server). If your question really is "when something changes in the web server, how can I update the clients?" then the answer is probably [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [socket.io](http://socket.io/), and similar techniques.